# PL/SQL stored procedure error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

This is the code I have written in PL/SQL I am trying to read data from a csv file and insert into a table in an Oracle database.

Normally when I insert timestamp values I do the following

```
insert into t (start_time) values 
(TO_TIMESTAMP('12-SEP-12 10.31.19','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS'))
```

Now I am getting error, from these lines on wards as shown below

> f_call_start:=to_timestamp(substr(l_line,comma2+1,comma3-comma2-1),'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS');
>       Error(38,28): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SUBSTR'

```
call_record_processor('calldata');
```

```
create or replace procedure call_record_processor(file_name_input in varchar2)
is
l_file UTL_FILE.file_type;
l_line varchar2(100);
l_eof boolean:=false;
comma1 varchar2(10);
comma2 varchar2(10);
comma3 varchar2(10);
comma4 varchar2(10);

f_source_no call_usage.source_phone_number%type;
f_dest_no call_usage.destination_phone_number%type;
f_call_start call_usage.call_start_time%type;
f_call_end call_usage.call_end_time%type;

begin
l_file:=UTL_FILE.fopen('c:\temp\',file_name_input,'r');

loop
  begin
  utl_file.get_line(l_file,l_line);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_line);
  EXCEPTION
  when no_data_found then
   exit;
  end;
comma1:=INSTR(l_line,',',1,1);
comma2:=INSTR(l_line,',',1,2);
comma3:=INSTR(l_line,',',1,3);
comma4:=INSTR(l_line,',',1,4);

f_source_no:=SUBSTR(l_line,1,comma1-1);
dbms_output.put_line('source_phone_number='||f_source_no);

f_dest_no:=SUBSTR(l_line,comma1+1,comma2-comma1-1);
dbms_output.put_line('destination_phone_number='||f_dest_no);

f_call_start:=to_timestamp(substr(l_line,comma2+1,comma3=comma2-1),'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS');
dbms_output.put_line('call_start_time='||f_call_start);

f_call_end:=to_timestamp(substr(l_line,comma3+1,comma4-comma3-1),'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS');
dbms_output.put_line('call_end_time='||f_call_end);

insert into call_usage values(f_source_no,f_dest_no,f_call_start,f_call_end);
end loop;
utl_file.fclose(l_file);
COMMIT;
end call_record_processor;
```

Comment: You are missing the underscore in `PUT_LINE`.  Well, now you are dynamically changing the question.  In the old days, we used to say RTFM! for syntax errors!  Spend a little time looking up the arguments for substr.

Comment: Yeah I realized that very silly mistake of mine, but I am getting the following error now Error(38,28): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SUBSTR' from this line on wards f_call_start:=to_timestamp(substr(l_line,comma2+1,comma3=comma2-1),'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS');

Comment: Yeah, that you just need to look up yourself and ask a more specific question if still needed. Also if you are referring to line numbers then add them before posting.  I doubt anyone is going to count lines. Not at 17:00 on a Thursday anyway. :-/  Hint because I am a nice guy: your equal sign doesn't belong.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `dbms_output.put_line`

Comment: Yeah I realised  that now very silly mistake, but I am getting the following error now Error(38,28): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SUBSTR' from this line on wards f_call_start:=to_timestamp(substr(l_line,comma2+1,comma3=comma2-1),'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS');

Comment: Can you print out what is substr(l_line,comma2+1,comma3=comma2-1)? That would be easier to debug. I guess the the string format does not fit into ''DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS'' very likely.